# How to disable anydesk (version 6.3.0) autostart in ubuntu?

Tags: autostart, anydesk

In this version there is no autostart.conf file in anydesk directory. In this case how can we disable autostart?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Anydesk installs a systemd unit. You should be able to disable it with the following command:

`sudo systemctl disable anydesk`

Comment: yes, it is working. thanks a lot.